# South East Double Arrow in Latex

Tags: symbols

Just wondering how I can produce a south-east double arrow like this:

[image]

Ok great there is a reverse lookup for latex symbols .. my new favourite link. thank you !

but i still think this is a valid question. good way to find the next important link.

also this:

[image]

Comment: You could just use `\rotatebox{-45}{$\Rightarrow$}`, where `\rotatebox` requires the `graphicx` package. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/121799) for more informations on how to look up symbols.

Comment: A variation on @marmot's suggestion: If the southeast-pointing double arrow is a relational operator, consider defining a macro called `\SEarrow` as follows: `\newcommand\SEarrow{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\Rightarrow$}}}`. Then, in the body of the document, write `$X\SEarrow Y$`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Requires LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\Searrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also load the symbol from another font, e.g. `txfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Searrow}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{117}
\begin{document}
$\Searrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to add that `\Searrow`, `\Nearrow`, etc are provided automatically by the `newtxmath` and `newpxmath` font packages. (In a way, this isn't surprising as `newtxmath` and `newpxmath` are derived from `txfonts` and `pxfonts`, respectively.)

Answer (score 6):

The `newtxmath` and `newpxmath` math font packages provide macros called `\Nearrow`, `\Nwarrow`, `\Swarrow` and `\Searrow`. These arrows (a) take up the same *width* as `\Rightarrow` and `\Leftarrow`, respectively, and (b) are 1.4 times as *long* as `\Rightarrow` and `\Leftarrow`.

If you either don't wish to use the `newtxmath` and `newpxmath` math font packages -- say, because you don't like or aren't allowed to use Times Roman and Palatino fonts -- or find that the arrows produced by `\Nearrow`, `\Nwarrow`, `\Swarrow` and `\Searrow` look too long, it's straightforward (by using the `\rotatebox` macro of the `graphicx` package) to create angled double-struck arrows that (a) take up the same width as `\Rightarrow` and (b) are as long `\Rightarrow` as.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % or: \usepackage{newpxmath}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\rotatebox' macro
\newcommand\myrot[1]{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{$\Rightarrow$}}}
% create four new angled double-struck arrows
\newcommand\NEarrow{\myrot{45}}
\newcommand\NWarrow{\myrot{135}}
\newcommand\SWarrow{\myrot{-135}}
\newcommand\SEarrow{\myrot{-45}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
a \Rightarrow b\\ \hline
a \Nearrow b\\
a \Nwarrow b\\
a \Swarrow b\\
a \Searrow b\\ \hline
a \NEarrow b\\
a \NWarrow b\\
a \SWarrow b\\
a \SEarrow b
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```